# Regarding my ignition switch issue?

Tags: java, methods, boolean, logic

I am currently working on my assignment called Car, and what it requires me to do is to setup 6 methods which are `randomizePosition`, `randomizeColor`, `reportState`, `ignitionSwitch`, `moveHorizontally`, and `moveVertically`.

I think I am done making the `randomizePosition` and `randomizeColor`, and `reportState`, but there is this problem with the `ignitionSwitch`. I set the value of `ignitionStat` to false (since the car is off), and I have made the `ignitionSwitch` method that takes boolean `ignitionStat` and made it return the opposite value.

I tried to set up the codes in a way where i will set up another String `ignitionStatus` and its value will be either `"ON"` (if the `ignitionSwitch` returned true) and `"OFF"` for the other case.  But despite trying, I always see that the `ignitionStatus` will be always `ON` even if the `ignitionStatus` returned `false`.

So I can't even figure out how should I approach this issue, and I think this is really crucial part since I need the ignition status to actually create methods moveHorizontally and moveVertically.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class testcar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int repeat = 1;
        boolean ignitionStat = false;

        while (repeat == 1) {

        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1: turn the ignition on/off");
        System.out.println("2: change the position of car");
        System.out.println("q: quit this program ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner ex = new Scanner(System.in);
        String i = sc.nextLine();
        switch (i) {
            case "1":
                System.out.println("You chose to turn on/off the ignition");
                                    ignitionSwitch(ignitionStat);
                                    System.out.println("CAR INFORMATION");
                                    System.out.println("IGNITION STATUS: ");
                reportState();
                                    repeat = 1;
                break;
            case "2":
                System.out.println("THIS WILL BE CHANGE POSITION METHOD");
                                    repeat = 2;
                break;
            case "q":
                System.out.println("You choose to quit");
                repeat = 0;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("INVALID OPTION");
                break;
        }
    }
            while (repeat == 2){
                System.out.println ("In which direction do you want to move the car? ");
                Scanner hv= new Scanner (System.in);
                String z = hv.nextLine();
                switch (z) {
                    case "h":
                        System.out.println("You will move the car horizontally!");
                        repeat = 0;
                        break;
                    case "v":
                        System.out.println("You will move the car vertically!");
                        repeat = 0;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid Option!");
                        repeat = 2;
          break;
                }
            }

}
    public static boolean ignitionSwitch(boolean ignitionStat){
        return ignitionStat =! ignitionStat;
    }

public static void reportState(){
    int positionX = randomizePosition();
    int positionY = randomizePosition();
    char carColor = assignColor();
    System.out.println ("CAR INFORMATION");
    System.out.println ("Color : " + carColor);
    System.out.println ("Location:" + "(" +positionX +","+positionY +")");
    String grid = "--------------------";
    for (int i =1; i<21; i++){
        if (i != positionY){
            System.out.println(grid);
        }
        else if (i == positionY){
            String newgrid = grid.substring(0,positionX-1) + carColor + grid.substring(0,20-positionX);
            System.out.println(newgrid);
        }
    }
}
public static int randomizePosition () {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int position = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
    return position;
}

public static char assignColor () {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int colorNum = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
    char colorStr;

    switch (colorNum) {
        case 1: colorStr = 'G';
            break;
        case 2: colorStr = 'B';
            break;
        case 3: colorStr = 'W';
            break;
        case 4: colorStr = 'S';
            break;
        default : colorStr = 'R';
            break;
    }
    return (colorStr);
}
}
```

Comment: A wall of text with no paragraphs is really hard to read. I edited your text somewhat, but it is still borderline off-topic.  You need to learn to use a debugger and step through the code one line at a time to see what the code _actually_ does.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use StackOverflow effectively.  Specifically, questions containing _"So I can't even figure out how should I approach this issue"_ are considered off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue. Your return statement `ignitionStat =! ignitionStat;` is only modifying the passed in variable. Change it to this:

```
public static boolean ignitionSwitch()
{
    return ignitionStat = !ignitionStat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But my assignment requires that ignitionSwitch method will just take ignitionStat's value and always return the opposite. However, I realized that there is something more, which is that it always returns true instead of returning the opposite... I am really lost now

Comment: @Harry Try implementing these new changes.

Comment: Would love an explanation for the downvote I received??

Comment: I did not downvote you :( I dont know too ... I tried implementing the changes, but it would still give me some piles of errors.

Comment: What are your errors? I am heading out now but can look later.

Comment: I got new sets of code , but my ignitionSwitch is still not fixed. So it keeps returning one value instead of returning the opposite .  E.g.  Initially, it takes false into the method, returns true. But when I use the method again, it still returns true where true was taken and false should be returned according to the ignitionSwitch method :(